# Exception flow understanding PHP

Tags: php, exception

I am going through PHP docs for Exception class and I am pretty new to OOP PHP and thus for exception handling with PHP predefined and SPL classes.

While going I have trouble getting the execution flow of example listed there.

```
<?php

class MyCustomException extends Exception {}

function doStuff() {
    try {
       throw new InvalidArgumentException("You are doing it wrong!", 112);
   } catch(Exception $e) {
    throw new MyCustomException("Something happened", 911, $e);
    }
}


try {
    doStuff();
} catch(Exception $e) {
 do {
    printf("%s:%d %s (%d) [%s]\n", $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getMessage(), $e-   >getCode(), get_class($e));
   } while($e = $e->getPrevious());
 }
   ?>
```

Here's my understanding so far.

1. The parser interprets a function and allocates memory  for the same.
2. It enters the try block and executes the dostuff();
3. What goes after this ...and how does the output turns out to be as per the sequence as shown below is not clear to me i.e MyCustomException appearing first.

`/home/bjori/ex.php:8 Something happened (911) [MyCustomException]
/home/bjori/ex.php:6 You are doing it wrong! (112) [InvalidArgumentException]`

Anyone please shed a light on it ! Many Thanks !

Comment: You catch an exception, which stops its propagation. You then throw another exception (the fact that one is linked to the other is irrelevant) which is propagated from then on. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **doStuff();**  you are throwing first an **InvalidArgumentException** (first exception) and that is caught within **doStuff();** and there you throw it again as **MyCustomException** (second exception). So in the outer try and catch block the **last** thrown exception is the **MyCustomException** and therefore the **previous** exception is/was the **InvalidArgumentException**.

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php

> Returns previous Exception (the third parameter of Exception::__construct()).

Hope that helps.